# How can i build HBase 2.0.0 and include hbase-spark?

Tags: hbase

I have an HBase 2.0.0 server up and running, and an HBase 2.0.0 client working with it. Now I want to also use the hbase-spark 2.0 connector, in order to use Spark 2.x rather than 1.6. It seems that the latest published JAR of hbase-spark is only 2.0.0-alpha4.

I tried to build HBase 2.0.0 myself, and it works, but it looks like hbase-spark is not on the 2.0 branch (only builds with the default branch, which seems 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT).

I managed to get the hbase-spark-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT to work, but it would be nice to be able to build the formal 2.0.0 version. How can I do that? Or are there some reasons not to do it?